# Brand new 2021 Nissan Rogue

Tags: oil, nissan, rogue

We purchased a brand new Nissan Rogue with 11 miles on it. After driving it for 5 days the ‘check oil” notification came on. We had driven less than 100 miles. We checked the oil and there was a small amount reading dip stick.  Did this do any permanent damage to the car since we had very little oil in it from day one?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

More than likely if there is still some oil in the engine, there is no damage done. With only a few hundred miles on the vehicle, the oil should be new and therefore should be good for some time, even if it is low.

What you need to be doing is getting it back to the dealership and figuring out why it was low on oil. Coming from the factory, it's HIGHLY unlikely it left there that way. There may be a leak, but whatever ... this should fall DIRECTLY on the dealership/manufacturer to get it fixed. This should be covered directly under the warranty.

Comment: HIghly unlikely, maybe. I used to share a house with a guy who previously ran his own garage business, but because of medical problems was then employed by a large dealership to check new vehicles. He once discovered the cause of "low oil level" was a 6 inch long crack in the engine sump. (The crack was actually found *after* topping up the oil level, and finding half a gallon of oil on the showroom floor the next day!!!)

Comment: There are no oil stains in my garage or my assigned parking space at work. The engine is clean. They came to our house and put 2 quarts of oil in it. Going to the dealership tomorrow to figure it our. Thanks for everyone’s input.